# Show fewer pages in Django pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am working on a Django application and on one of the pages we use pagination. I have around 200 pages and if I am somewhere in the middle then it has links from page 1 - 4, displays the 4 pages behind the page I am on, 3 after the page I am on and the last 4 pages. Looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Up5z.jpg)

I would like it so that it shows fewer pages at a time, maybe the first 2, the last 2 and the current page I am on +/- 2.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load pagination_tags %}

{% load staticfiles %}
    {% block body_block %}

        {% autopaginate art 4 %}

        <div class="container">
            {% if item%}
                {% for x in item %}
                    <div class="floated_img">
                        {% if x.picture %}
                            <img src="{{ x.picture.url }}" name="aboutme" width="140" height="140"
                                 class="img-rounded" class="img-responsive">
                        {% else %}
                            <img src="{% static "images/generic.jpg" %}" name="aboutme" width="140" height="140"
                                 class="img-rounded" class="img-responsive">
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <p style="text-align: center;">

                                <strong>{{ x.name }}</strong><br>
                                <strong>{{ x.type }}</strong><br>
                                <strong>{{ x.price }}</strong>
                        </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        <br>

        {% paginate %}


    {% endblock %}
```

I have not written any python files for pagination and have just imported things in, I assume I will have to make changes to some of the pagination files and store them within my project to override them but don't know how to go about doing this.

Would be grateful for the help and hope I have given enough information about my problem

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the [django-pagination](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination) app. It has a setting for the number of items left and right of the current page

- `PAGINATION_DEFAULT_WINDOW` The number of items to the left and to the right of the current page to display (accounting for ellipses).

So setting

```
PAGINATION_DEFAULT_WINDOW = 2
```

would set the middle part as required.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it. Is there a way I can copy that part of the django pagination app into my project so that it overrides it and when other people use it they will see it that way as well? If I change my copy it will only affect my copy of pagination